# Do friends continue to use chan/kun to refer to each other as adults or do they switch to using san?

Tags: grammar, politeness, suffixes, honorifics

Do friends continue to use chan/kun to refer to each other as adults or do they switch to using san?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on people themselves or relationship between each other.

Comment: Examples please?